# Add dynamic number of QLabel and QLineEdit inside a tab widget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to make a button that when press, it will generate a label and line edit. I tried using this code but the label will goes to the mainwindow. I want to put that on tabwidget page I create on QT designer.

```py
    def predict_student(self):
        self.label = QLabel('This is label', self)
        self.label.show()
```

Comment: QTabWidget has child pages, in which page do you want it to create the label? Should it be added as a *new* page, or to an existing one? And how? Are you using [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)? Are pages created dynamically? To what class does that function belong? Please, try to put more efforts when creating questions, we are not clairvoyants, we cannot know what your code does if you don't provide a proper [mre]. Take your time to review the [tour] and read [ask], and most importantly make your purposes clear.

Comment: Sorry for that. I created it the UI in Qt Designer. The label should be added inside on a existing page. The button must generate a form-like, which have labels and line edit inside a page on tabwidget. The function belong to my class main window. Let me try to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem by creating a form layout inside the page and adding the label on that specific layout.

```
def predict_student(self):
        self.label1 = QLabel('This is label', self)
        self.formLayout.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.label1.show()
```